# Mountain Lion Share Sheet Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: macos

Using the Keyboard Preference Pane, I've assigned shortcuts to the items in the share sheet in the Finder. Command-Option-Control-M for "Email" and Command-Option-Control-C for Message. The keyboard shortcuts actually get listed next to those commands when I click on the share sheet.

[image: My keyboard shortcuts]

But they don't actually work. I've tried relaunching Finder and restarting, but to no avail. Any ideas to kickstart these commands, or is it just a glitch that they even appear in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

Though these actions can be given shortcuts for All Applications, it does not  appear that they will work in all apps. For example, Finder and Safari will not recognize them, but Preview will. I'm not sure if this is the intended functionality—due to some of the applications having application-specific sharing options—or a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It only works if you highlight the file as text selection, not as file selection. So it grabs the name of the file into Apple Mail instead of a whole file attachment. It looks like a bug and I don't think Apple intends to have it working that way. I had submitted the bug to Apple and hope they fix this issue on the next update.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens with other more exotic menu items:

[image]

The custom shortcuts are shown next to their titles, but only work in some cases like if the menus are expanded.

So it's probably just a glitch.